# Can't serialize transient record type postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to make my calculation dynamic based on certain criteria as below, but when I try to send the fields dynamically in to my calculation logic, it fails with the error " Can't serialize transient record type":

Create table statement :

```
create table calculation_t(
    Id serial,
    product_id integer not null,
    metric_id integer not null,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    calculation_logic varchar(50),
    insert_timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT calculation_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    CONSTRAINT calculation_pid_fk FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES Product_T(Product_id),
    CONSTRAINT calc_mid_fk FOREIGN KEY(metric_id) REFERENCES metric_T(metric_id)
    );
```

Insert statement :

```
insert into calculation_t(product_id,metric_id,calculation_logic)
select a.product_id,b.metric_id,
(case when b.metric_id=2 then
('$1-$2') else
'$1/$2' end) calc
from product_t a,metric_t b
```

Select statement which throws the mentioned error :

```
 select *,(1,2,calculation_logic) from calculation_t
```

Note : I am using Greenplum database.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with PostgreSQL 8.4 or 9.3. Are you sure you want to use a row constructor in your SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove parenthesis form your query:

```
select *,1,2,calculation_logic from calculation_t
```

It worked for me.
Thanx,